# RemoteAction Not Working with Standard Controller

Tags: javascript-remoting, remote-action

I'm attempting to pass some JavaScript variables to an apex controller. I am using JavaScript Remoting, but I'm seeing an 'OpportunityStandardController.RemoteAction' error when I attempt to deploy. Is there a reason why the standard opportunity controller stops my class from deploying rather than checking the extension controller?

Comment: We'll need to see some code to help you figure out the problem. Please [edit] your question to show enough code for us to help you.

Comment: I removed an apex:actionFunction element and the error when away. I'm facing another error now: 'unable to invoke action "class.method" no controller and/or function found'. Has anyone figured resolved this error?

Comment: you'll need to post your controller/VF page - relevant bits only - use [edit]